# Como consigo que el WHILE me coja la variable

Tags: java, while

Soy muy novato con JAVA y estoy intentando hacer que en mi WHILE la condición sea distinta al tipo de vehiculo ( es una especie de concesionario). Pero por algun motivo no me funciona y no logro entender el porque.

Mi problema esta en que el  } while ("F".equal(!typeVehicle)); me lo marca como error pero no encuentro el error, el eclipse me marca como que no esta inicianilida la variable.

Mi idea es que cuando introduzcas la palabra F deje de pedirte vehiculos.

```
package com.alicante.proyecto3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.alicante.proyecto3.domain.Bike;
import com.alicante.proyecto3.domain.Car;
import com.alicante.proyecto3.domain.IVehicle;
import com.alicante.proyecto3.domain.Motorbike;
import com.alicante.proyecto3.domain.Vehicle;

public class Workshop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wkenrollment;
        String wkbrand;
        String wkmodel;
        List<IVehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("INSTRUCCIONES: ");
        System.out.println("Para finalizar introduzca de tipo de vehiculo F");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        do {
            System.out.print("Introduzca el tipo de vehiculo ");
            String typeVehicle = console.nextLine();
            final Vehicle vehicle;
            if ("C".equals(typeVehicle)) {
                vehicle = new Car();
                System.out.println("Inserte la matricula");
                wkenrollment = console.nextLine();
                vehicle.setEnrollment(wkenrollment);
                System.out.println("Inserte la marca");
                vehicle.setBrand(wkbrand);
                System.out.println("Inserte el modelo");
                vehicle.setModel(wkmodel);
                vehicleList.add(vehicle);
            } else if ("M".equals(typeVehicle)) {
                vehicle = new Motorbike();
                System.out.println("Inserte la matricula");
                wkenrollment = console.nextLine();
                vehicle.setEnrollment(wkenrollment);
                System.out.println("Inserte la marca");
                vehicle.setBrand(wkbrand);
                System.out.println("Inserte el modelo");
                vehicle.setModel(wkmodel);
                vehicleList.add(vehicle);
            } else if ("B".equals(typeVehicle)) {
                vehicle = new Bike();
                System.out.println("Inserte la marca");
                vehicle.setBrand(wkbrand);
                System.out.println("Inserte el modelo");
                vehicle.setModel(wkmodel);
                vehicleList.add(vehicle);
            } else {

                System.out.print("No ha introducido un vehiculo correcto, por favor añada un correcto (C/B/M) ");
            }
        } while ("F".equal(!typeVehicle));
        console.close();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Tu taller tiene los siguientes vehiculos:");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");

        for (IVehicle i : vehicleList) {
            System.out.println("Matricula del vehiculo: " + i.getModel());
            System.out.println("Marca del vehiculo: " + i.getBrand());
            System.out.println("Modelo del vehiculo: " + i.getEnrollment());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El error es que debes declarar esa variable fuera del while, dado que la toma como una variable local dentro del ciclo.

Esto marca error:

```
do{
    String hola = "e";
}while("e".equals(hola)); // Variable 'hola' no declarada
```

deberia ser:

```
String hola;
do{
   hola = "e";
}while("e".equals(hola));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos problemas. El primero es que la variable `typeVehicle` no es accesible para el `while` porque la tienes declarada dentro del ámbito de este (dentro de las llaves). El segundo problema es que estás intentando aplicar el operador negación (!) a una variable de tipo `String`. Este operador solo es válido para variables o expresiones booleanas. Lo que quieres hacer se hace de esta forma:

```
String typeVehicle = null;
do {
    // Aquí cualquier código
} while (!"F".equal(typeVehicle));
```

Nota como moví el operador hacia el inicio de la expresión booleana `"F".equals(typeVehicle)`.